# When does Hibernate Session.load() throw an exception

Tags: hibernate, session, exception, load

```
try {
   x = session.load(...); 
   y = x; 
 }
 catch(Exception e) {
    //do something
 }
```

If the key is not present, will load(...) throw an exception

1. right away
2. will return a proxy and then throw an exception
   when the object is trying to be obtained from the db later?

Also, in the code above, if the execution reaches the assignment y = x, is it guaranteed that at that point, x is not null? Are there situations where x can be null at that point?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short:**

- `x` will not be null after the load, so neither will `y`
- There may or may not be an exception from `load()` if the object doesn't exist
- If there is no exception from `load()`, and the object doesn't exist, there will be an exception when accessing `x` or `y`.

**To elaborate:**

Are you trying to determine if the key is present? Or are you assuming it is, but just want to handle anomalies?

See the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29), specifically:

> You should not use this method to determine if an instance exists (use `get()` instead). Use this only to retrieve an instance that you assume exists, where non-existence would be an actual error.

From the book 'hibernate in action' on using load():

> The application may retrieve a valid reference (a proxy) to a 
>   persistent instance without hitting the database to retrieve its persistent state. So 
>   `load()` might not throw an exception when it doesn’t find the persistent object 
>   in the cache or database; the exception would be thrown later, when the proxy 
>   is accessed.

**So**:

If you are looking to know whether the item exists, use `get()`, not `load()`.

Comment: +1 -- technically, it can throw an exception after you get the object **if** the object is lazy loaded.  So I was wrong.

Comment: thanks @Tass. I will take this as the correct answer and proceed.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the response by @Tass, I found out (thanks to a co-worker)

1. the exception is thrown right away if @Proxy(lazy="false")
2. the exception is not thrown if @Proxy(lazy="true")