# why session.load throw exception in Hibernate when not found requested object on basis of identifier?

Tags: java, hibernate

Why does session.load throw an exception when the requested object is not found by its identifier? Please
clarify?

Comment: It doesn't. Please clarify. Show us code, tell us what you expect it to do, and what it does instead. Precisely.

Comment: please relate it with session.get ,when use  session.get return any object including null.but session.load throw exception.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Read the javadoc: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29. Do you see any exception listed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659485/when-does-hibernate-session-load-throw-an-exception

Answer (score 0):

Because when using session.load the existence of the object is assumed. If you're not sure if the object exists, use `session.get(..)`. This will return `null` if the object doesn't exist.

Note @ JB Nizet: a runtime exception need not be declared - so it's perfectly alright if `session.load(..)` throws something like an `IllegalArgumentException`.

Comment: The fact is: it doesn't throw an exception. As your answer says: it assumes that the entity exists and returns an uninitialized proxy (or the real entity if already in the session). So it will not throw an exception if the entity doesn't exist.

Comment: i want know reason what internally load does?

Comment: It does what the javadoc tells it does. What don't you understand in the javadoc?